# Validation for empty input is skipped if using ctype_alnum() or preg_match()

Tags: php

I have this validation code:

```
public function validate() {

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

            foreach ($this->required as $field) {

                if (empty($_POST[$field])) {    
                    $this->error = $this->message['required'];
                }
            }

            if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['text'])) {
                $this->error = $this->message['text']['alphanum'];
            }

            if (strlen($_POST['text']) > 3) {
                $this->error = $this->message['text']['length'];
            }
        }
        return $this->error;
    }
```

The problem is that even if the `'text'` input is empty, it skips the `if (empty($_POST[$field]))` statement and goes to the `if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['text']))` statement instead, displaying its error.

If I comment out the `if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['text']))` statement, then it works properly and displays the "This field is required" error if the 'text' input is empty on submission.

It also works if I get the statement out of the foreach loop and use `elseif`, like this:

```
if (empty($_POST['text'])) {
  $this->error = $this->message['required'];
} elseif (!ctype_alnum($_POST['text'])) {
  $this->error = $this->message['text']['alphanum'];
}
```

But I'd like to use the loop and not use elseif, especially because I'll have a lot of required fields to validate.

I also tried:

- Removing the `if (empty($_POST[$field]))` statement from the loop and adding it as the other ones: `if (empty($_POST['text']))`;
- Using `$_POST['text'] == ''` instead of `empty()`;
- Using `strlen($_POST['text']) == 0` instead of `empty()`;
- Using `preg_match()` instead of `ctype_alnum`.

This shows when I use `var_dump($_POST['text'])` and submitting with an empty input:

`/home/vagrant/code/test/index.php:13:string '' (length=0)`

I can't figure out why and how to make it not skip the empty validation when using ctype_alnum() or preg_match().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest just checking if the 'text' field is empty before checking any other criteria on it like this:

```
public function validate() {

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        foreach ($this->required as $field) {

            if (empty($_POST[$field])) {    
                $this->error = $this->message['required'];
            }
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['text']) {
            if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['text'])) {
                $this->error = $this->message['text']['alphanum'];
            }

            if (strlen($_POST['text']) > 3) {
                $this->error = $this->message['text']['length'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->error;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are overwriting `$this->error` if following conditions hold `true`, i.e. you won't get a `$this->message['required']` back if the next condition, `!ctype_alnum($_POST['text'])` is true and overwrites `$this->error` with its message.

So you need to return `$this->message` inside each condition.

```
public function validate() {

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        foreach ($this->required as $field) {

            if (empty($_POST[$field])) {    
                $this->error = $this->message['required'];
                return $this->error;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['text']) {
            if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['text'])) {
                $this->error = $this->message['text']['alphanum'];
                return $this->error;
            }

            if (strlen($_POST['text']) > 3) {
                $this->error = $this->message['text']['length'];
                return $this->error;
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->error;
}
```

Comment: You're right. Now I see it. Thanks! It appears to be working without using return in every statement, though, as @Cody604 showed.